# Odoo 12 num2words Amount To Text

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-accounting

I'm new in this community and I setting up Odoo Community version for my little comapny. I does all the things just doesn't know how to set up num2words to show Total Amount in Invoice Reports!

I found num2words api in res_currency.py in Base/Modules but I spend two days researching how to connect and nothing. What I have to inherite and how and also what to put in invoice document qweb?

**I made module like this:**

```py
from num2words import num2words

class account_invoice(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.invoice"

 @api.multi
def amount_to_text(self, amount):
    self.ensure_one()
    def _num2words(number, lang):
        try:
            return num2words(number, lang=lang).title()
        except NotImplementedError:
            return num2words(number, lang='en').title()

if num2words is None:
        logging.getLogger(__name__).warning("The library 'num2words' is missing, cannot render textual amounts.")
        return ""

formatted = "%.{0}f".format(self.decimal_places) % amount
    parts = formatted.partition('.')
    integer_value = int(parts[0])
    fractional_value = int(parts[2] or 0)

    lang_code = self.env.context.get('lang') or self.env.user.lang
    lang = self.env['res.lang'].search([('code', '=', lang_code)])
    amount_words = tools.ustr('{amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                    amt_value=_num2words(integer_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                    amt_word=self.currency_unit_label,
                    )
    if not self.is_zero(amount - integer_value):
        amount_words += ' ' + _('and') + tools.ustr(' {amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                    amt_value=_num2words(fractional_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                    amt_word=self.currency_subunit_label,
                    )
    return amount_words
```

**Got error like this:**

```
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'currency_id'
Template: account.report_invoice_document_with_payments
Path: /templates/t/t/div/p[1]/span
Node: <span t-if="doc.currency_id" t-esc="doc.currency_id.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/>
```

**In QWeb I put this:**

```xml
<span t-if="doc.currency_id" t-esc="doc.currency_id.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your case "**currency_id**" is a Many2one field. The '*res.currency*' model does not contain the class '**amount_to_text**' function.

You have written ***amount_to_text*** function in '*account.invoice*' model. So change your like this,

```
<span t-if="doc.currency_id" t-esc="doc.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/>
```

OR(if you don't have *currency_id* field in your object)

```
 <span t-if="doc.amount_to_text" t-esc="doc.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/>
```

Comment: I changed QWeb to: <span t-if="doc.currency_id" t-esc="doc.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/> and again same Error

Comment: In which object you have this report? If you don't have currency_id field please add that in your model, or else use company's currency(see my edited answer)

Comment: When I put new code now get error: Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'amount_to_text'

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
<span t-if="o.currency_id" t-esc="o.amount_to_text(o.amount_total)"/>
```

You are getting the error because in the base report they are using o instead of doc. please see the below part of code from base.

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
```

So try to use o instead of doc